# Laravel: Get ID on a FormRequest Rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I created a rule to check if email already exist only if the field was changed.

```
$rules = [
    'user-name'      => 'required',
    'user-email'     => [
        'required',
        'email',
        Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore(ID)
    ],
];
```

But I need to inform the user ID. How can I grab this information?

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController')->middleware('permission:create users');
```

Comment: Can you show your route ??

Comment: @Davit check the edit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your Form request you have access to the authenticated user, so you can use:

```
$this->user()->id
```

--- Edit

getting the id from the url:

```
request()->route('id')
```

-- Second try

```
$this->route('user')
```

Or print out using `php artisan route:list` and whatever is used on the url as `{user}` or `{id}` that's what you need to use.

Comment: This return the ID of the logged user. I need to get the user ID whose information is being edited: http://website.test/users/2/edit

Comment: `request()->route('id')` return empty on log.

Comment: I see now you are using resource, so try `$this->route('user')`. Or print out using `php artisan route:list` and whatever is used on the url as `{user}` or `{id}` that's what you need to use.

Comment: Fixed! If you edit your answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: For anyone using Resources in your routes file, it's worth noting that a hyphenated route i.e. `my-model`  will become `my_model` when you are looking for the parameters, i.e. `$this->route('my_model')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```php
$id = app('request')->segment(2);
```

I'm not sure, but maybe it will work:

```php
$id = app('request')->user_id;
```

Comment: $id = app('request')->segment(2);
worked for me. i had to get the third part though :D

Comment: `$id = app('request')->user_id;` worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this code.** I'm using this code to get request-id when update data, and it works for me.

```php
$id = $this->route('params_name');
```